# Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on string

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image, laravel-5.4

In my laravel controller when i try to upload image i get this error..

My I Know what the problem is
This is inside my controller

```
  $image = $request['images'];
        if ($image)
        {
            $imgfile = $request['images'];                                                                                                                                                                 
            $imgpath = 'uploads/users/images/'.$user->id;
            File::makeDirectory($imgpath, $mode = 0777, true, true);
            $imgDestinationPath = $imgpath.'/'; // upload folder in public directory
            $ext1 = $imgfile->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename1 = uniqid('vid_').'.'.$ext1;
            $usuccess = $imgfile->move($imgDestinationPath, $filename1);

        }
```

This is my jquery code my form id is update profile and i get all the field values by its name

```
$("#updateprofile").on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(e);
        var redirect_url = $(this).find("[name='redirect_url']").val();
        var url = $(this).attr('action');
        var method = $(this).attr('method');
           var myData = {
                name: $(this).find("[name='name']").val(),
                gender:$(this).find("[name='gender']").val(),
                lastname:$(this).find("[name='lastname']").val(),
                email:$(this).find("[name='email']").val(),
                mobile:$(this).find("[name='mobile']").val(),
                address:$(this).find("[name='address']").val(),
                city: $(this).find("[name='city']").val(),
                state:$(this).find("[name='state']").val(),
                country:$(this).find("[name='country']").val(),
                pin:$(this).find("[name='pin']").val(),
                images: document.getElementById('imageToUpload').files[0],
            }
        console.log("data", myData);
       $.ajax({
              type: "PUT",
              url: url,
              dataType: 'JSON',
              data: myData,
              success: function(data) {
                  console.log(data);
                  //alert("Profile update successfully")
                  //window.location.href = redirect_url;
              },
              error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  alert("das");
                  console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                  console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
              }
          });
    });
```

Comment: `$imgfile` is a string, so probably `$request['images']` gives you only the name of the file, not the file object itself. According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#files), you can access your file via `$request->file('image')`. Or are there multiple files?

Comment: post the outout of print_r($request['images']);\

Comment: Yes But while giving `$request->file('image')` it show me an error like this in my console window  `jquery.min.js:3130 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

Comment: Jquery won't give you an error in the backend, you seem to send something incorrect back to the browser.

Comment: @TobiasF. i cant get you what you are saying

Comment: PHP = Backend and jquery = frontend, so i wanted to make clear that the PHP part and jquery are "completly" independent from each other because ti sounded to me you thought jquery broke somthing in the backend :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming your form input's `id` and `name` value is `images`),

```
 if($request->hasFile('images')) {
            $imgfile = Input::file('images');
            $imgpath = 'uploads/users/images/'.$user->id;
            File::makeDirectory($imgpath, $mode = 0777, true, true);
            $imgDestinationPath = $imgpath.'/';
            $ext1 = $imgfile->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename1 = uniqid('vid_').'.'.$ext1;
            $usuccess = $imgfile->move($imgDestinationPath, $filename1);
        }
```

In your jQuery code :
try changeing

```
images: document.getElementById('imageToUpload').files[0],
```

to

```
images: document.getElementById('imageToUpload').files[0].value,
```

and as you are uploading files through your form yous should specify `contentType: 'multipart/form-data',` in your ajax call

Comment: Thanks Sapnesh but it shows an error like this  `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

Comment: @Karthiga okay apart from the jQuery error is the image being stored as expected?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144034/discussion-between-karthiga-and-sapnesh-naik).